# Follow the sent form

Tags: php, guzzle

Is possible to do set form data and follow redirect by action in any http client in PHP?

For example I have Guzzle:

```
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://example.com/login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'login' => 'admin',
            'pass' => 'admin'
        ]
    ]);
```

Instead get data to variable $response, I would like to be redirected to https://example.com/login, same as if I would send a form manually.

I can do one additional step where I generate form and send it by javascript, but I would like to skip this step.

Comment: You can redirect like this: `header("Location: https://example.com/login");
exit;`

Comment: @ChibaAndrei but without data...

Comment: you can send data like this: `header("Location: https://example.com/login?data=value&data2=value2");` and get it through `$_GET` after redirect

Comment: But I have to have POST request, not GET.

Comment: I’m not sure that what you’re trying to do is possible. Guzzle is effectively a browser within your code, so it can follow that link (and is being asked to do so), but it can’t take the user there. But, Guzzle can tell you where the server it submitted the data would like to go. Then you could redirect the user there yourself. It’s not possible to force a user to submit a POST request without them submitting a form, as the request has to come from the user’s browser – not your server.

Comment: you can do it with `$_SESSION['post_data'] = your data` and get the data from `$_SESSION` on the other page, i'm not 100% sure but i dont think you can do a POST request without a form in your case